# Clone a Retrieve and Rank

Tags: solr, ibm-cloud, watson, retrieve-and-rank

so we were creating a Retrieve and Rank Service on Bluemix and we now want to move it to another organisation within Bluemix.
Is there any way to export the complete set of answerunits, questions and rankings?
I guessed it might be possible to just clone the SOLR Cluster.

The export button in the Bluemix-webinterface sadly only exports a fragment of the ranking.

even if it is a completely manual task I would be happy.

Greetings:
Junge

Comment: I would recommend opening a support ticket with Bluemix. They should be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Question can be seen as resolved, since IBM refined the exporting process. As of now it is possible to export the complete ranking.

Answer units and questions should have been saved locally. 
If that is not the case, the questions can be retrieved from the exported ranking. (All you need to do is to write a simple script that filters them out) for the documents that sadly is not the case.